# Retrieve x random elements from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am struggling to write a clean method which when passed an array of strings and x returns a randomised list of array elements totalling x, eg.

```
def getrandomarrayelements(thearray, howmany)
    return [something]
end
```

Yes I should submit my existing code, which whilst works is not good, it's 8 lines long and I have a feeling it can be done in one?!

Comment: That's a shuffle and a deal. There's a lot of prior art for that, no?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In ruby 1.9:

```
irb(main):001:0> [1,2,3,4,5].sample(3)
=> [2, 4, 5]
irb(main):002:0> [1,2,3,4,5].sample(3)
=> [2, 5, 3]
```

and for ruby 1.8 something like this:

```
def sample(arr, n)
  arr.shuffle[0...n]
end

irb(main):009:0> sample([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
=> [5, 1, 3]
irb(main):010:0> sample([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
=> [3, 4, 2]
```

Comment: In the 1.9 version, will that return unique elements, forgot to mention that in my question?